# JS for and while loops with jQuery ajax locks up in Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a friend that wants to incrementally move data from one db to another and display errors while doing that. I felt I could help by writing a quick script for him and I completed it in about an hour and works fine in Opera and Firefox (testing with dragonfly and firebug). When he tried it in Chrome, the browser locked up until the for or while loop was done and it took considerable longer to complete. Here is my code (without the error catch part that reads the json):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('#myForm').submit(function(form) {
    form.preventDefault();
    var increment = (jQuery("input#increment").val())*1;
    var total = jQuery("input#total").val();
    var progress = 0;
    jQuery("#progressbar").progressbar({value: 0});
    //for (progress = 0; progress < total; progress = progress + increment)
    while (progress < total)
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'progressBarAjax.php',
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                ajax: 'goAjax',
                total: total,
                increment: increment,
                progress: progress
            },
            success: function(data){
                jQuery("#progressbar").progressbar({value: data.value});
            }
        });
        progress = progress + increment;
    }
});
```

also, for further reference, the code for catching errors has been stripped during debugging and data.value = floor(($progress / $total) * 100). You can also see where I have tried both for and while and both work fine in Opera and Firefox but not Chrome.

Knowing why this behavior happens would be nice to know for future projects but also I would like to write it properly as well. The objectives are to take 200k inserts/updates and break them up in to smaller chunks, run the queries synchronously, and update a progress bar in the process.

Comment: Does the progress bar get updated  at the appropriate intervals on Chrome?

Comment: Progress bar does update if I put alert() in the middle of it but the browser is unresponsive until the while loop finishes.

increment is whatever is passed in the form. So if you can make total 500 and increment 100 and you should see the progress bar update 5 times @20% each. Works in FF and Opera, not Chrome.

Comment: So you are asking the browser to perform 'total' gets as fast as possible? You might just need to stagger or timer your gets so its not overwhelming the browser.

Comment: (Removed comment - missed the `async: false`.)

Comment: for testing, I have sleep(1) in the function replacing any real work and try only doing a total of two loops so first run will update the progress bar to 50, then 100% and it still runs fine in FF and Opera, just not Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're using `async:false` so the browser will lock while the request is made. That `while` can also get into an infinite loop if increment is 0..

I would think you actually want query the server, and if the server comes back and says it's not done yet in it's json response, then query it again, until it says it is. Something like:

```
var increment, total, progress;

function getProgress(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'progressBarAjax.php',
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            ajax: 'goAjax',
            total: total,           // Obviously, I don't know what these
            increment: increment,   // do on your server, so I've kept
            progress: progress      // them here.
        },
        success: function(data){
            // Assuming data.value is the progress from 1-100?
            // otherwise, figure out the progress from the data response
            progress = data.value;
            jQuery("#progressbar").progressbar({value: progress});
            if(progress < 100){
                getProgress();
            }else{
                // All done
                alert('done'); 
            }  
        }
    });
}

jQuery('#myForm').submit(function(form) {
    form.preventDefault();
    // Only go if we aren't currently.
    if(progress == null || progress == 100){
        increment = (jQuery("input#increment").val())*1;
        total = jQuery("input#total").val();
        progress = 0;
        getProgress();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try and redactor this to work. FYI, increment and progress are limit and offset in mysql. Total is total records we want. The function on the php page will take care of a lot more than what is shown but I wanted to simplify the example as best as I could to just what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The browser locking up is an expected behaviour if you are performing synchronous AJAX requests, especially if you are performing several of them in sequence.

From the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> async Boolean
>
> Default: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

It is possible that the document reads "may" because the behaviour is not consistent across browsers.  If you want to force the page to redraw, you must allow the JavaScript execution to terminate periodically.  To accomplish this, instead of using a while loop, call "nested" `setTimeout()`s or used asynchronous requests, and call the next request in the previous request's callback.